# Line labeling and referencing with lstinputlisting?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, labels, input

Say I had the following Fortran code saved as hello.f:

```
PROGRAM HELLO  
  PRINT '(A)', 'Hello, world'  
  STOP  
END
```

I know I can bring this into LaTeX with

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello}, escapechar=|]  
   PROGRAM HELLO  
     PRINT '(A)', 'Hello, world'     |\label{line:h1}|
     STOP  
   END  
\end{lstlisting}
```

Where I can use `~\ref{line:h1}` in regular text mode later on. Is it possible to do the same using `\lstinputlisting`?

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={Hello}]{./fortran/code/hello.f}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the label to your file, so the contents of hello.f should be

```
PROGRAM HELLO  
  PRINT '(A)', 'Hello, world'     |\label{line:h1}|
  STOP  
END
```

And then add the escape character to the `\lstinputlisting` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption={Hello}, escapechar=|]{hello.f}
See line~\ref{line:h1}.
\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX twice (to get the reference right), I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Can we use `escapechar` with `escapeinside`?